# Regex:password all character are allowed,but not include space

Tags: regex, passwords, space

Regex:password all character are allowed,but not include space,length is 8-16.please give me  an efftive  help.

Comment: I found the answer about this in stackoverflow  all were complex, but I want to have an easy one.

Comment: Why you want to limit the size and characters that your users can use in their passwords? Don't you want it to be secure?

Comment: I found that google have this issue,It is not count the length when your fill space in the end of password,your can go and have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following Regex...

```
^\S{8,16}$
```

Good Luck!

Comment: No,this way the special characters are not included, like".,/.[]$!#^%^" are not allowed;I want to fill all characters only space not  in it.

Comment: \S should cover all characters except space.

Comment: Oh,I think I should have a sleep.I have a badly understanding,I had checked some influential files, I think your are right ,thinks a lot.